# Max-width responsive width issues

Tags: html, css, width

I'm using max-width and width to make my website responsive to window size. 
My content div is not downsizing when the website is made smaller.

The content is told that its max width is 800px, and its set to be 100%. 
However its not downsizing when outercontainer does. 
Any thoughts?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas';
    src: url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/BEBAS.TTF)
}


body {
 background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/Background.png);
 max-width:1920px;
 width:100%;
 margin: auto;
}

.outercontainer{
      height:100%;
   max-width:1920px;
      width:100%
}

.container {
 max-width:960px;
 width:100%;
 max-height:300px;
 height:100%;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin:auto;


}

.header {
 background-image:url(Website%20Specific%20Resources/New_Banner_.png);
 max-height: 300px;
 max-width: 1920px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index:5;
}



A {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: "bebas";
 color: #fff;
 
}

li {
 z-index:2;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 padding-right:50px;
 margin-left:25px;
 padding-top:15px;
 font-size:24px;
 
 
}

.nav {
 z-index:2;
 
 position: absolute;
}
.content {
 font-family: "bebas";
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #009999;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
 <div class="outercontainer">
 <div class="header">
     <div class="container">            
      <div class="nav">
            
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About  Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact  Us </a></li>
        </ul>
        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       
       
        <div class="content" >
          <p>asdasdasdasdaf</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>asdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasda</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>sdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdafasdasdasdasdaf</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
       
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not really clear. What do you want exactly ? It worked fine in my browser. It resizes to a max 800px width, when shorter the container gets short as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far i can see it's resizing well in chrome. however i think you forgot to add the meta tag for responsive layout `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: The actual container itself doesn't seem to be resizing for me (the entire blue area stays at width).
Not to sound noobly, but where would I add that tag?

Comment: `<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>index</title>
 <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
</head>` try this

Comment: also i think you need to add `body { background-position: 50% 50% }` in css to make the main background horizontally center.

Comment: That hasn't done it either unfortunately, 
I'm aware that the images aren't scaling, just trying to fix this problem first then fix the others haha.

Comment: i still don't understand. you replied to @rittam saying half of the problem is fixed. now what's the problem left? did you use meta that i gave you? please give me link after using that meta and i can have a further look into it

Comment: The problem is this: http://www.njdartistics.com/Fluid/index.html
The blue area should be resizing itself in ratio with the rest of the website. All other div's are becoming smaller upon resizing the window. The blue area is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114545/discussion-between-lucian-and-jordy-downie).

Answer (score 0):

Ur content is responsive. Since you are not giving space b/w letters that why it is not coming down. Add some space and check it out

```
<p>sdasdafasdasda sdasdafasdasdasdasdafa sdasdasdasdafas dasdasdasdafasd asdasdasdaf</p>
```

If you want break the word even without space. U can add the following one

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: I tried breaking the "filler" words up, but the content container doesn't shrink with window size. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can u put in fiddle and pass the link?

Comment: If you like, I could upload it to my domain?

Comment: So to add, Content is colored blue, and should get smaller when you resize your window down.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Apply Word-Wrap to your paragraph

**Word-wrap:**

Usage:

- Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line:

Implementation:

```
p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/uy2r6jh7/

Comment: Thank you for fixing half the problem. But, the actual content window isnt resizing.